# Display only one category on home page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show one category on my home page.
I use this code:

```
 <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
```

but this code shows all category of this post like this:

cat 1, cat 2, cat 3, cat 4, ....

but I don't want this. I want to show only one category like this:

cat 1

Comment: How do you want to decide on which category to show? Do you just want to show the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Comment: Thnx for replay ... your code is working .. But I wanna the first category link to go the category page.
and thanks again

Comment: @mohmal, you shouldn’t accept an answer that doesn’t actually answer your question. Accepting an answer marks your question as resolved, so no one else will look at it and try to help you. Accepted answers also tell *other* users that this answer will help them with the same problem, so if the accepted answer doesn’t work you are causing problems for those users too.

Comment: $category = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $category ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category[0]->cat_name ) . '</a>';
}